# Bluetooth dongle support for Ubislate 9ci tablet

Tags: bluetooth, usb-on-the-go, usb-peripherals

I purchased a new tablet Datawind Ubislate 9ci. It is a 9 inch no-bluetooth tablet.

Details:

- Android 4.1.1
- Rock chip RK2928
- Linux kernel version 3.0.36+

I want to attach a Bluetooth dongle to this tablet. I have micro USB OTG cable and Bluetooth USB 2.0. Please suggest and guide me on how to do this, with download links to ROM, firmware, etc.

I found a software from Google Play and it is recognising the BT USB 2.0, but it is not connecting to the tablet  I have run the USB host diagnostics; everything is showing "yes".

The BT Dongle is recognised by USB host controller version 0.44 from Google Play Store. It is showing as below:

> under info: s3c usb host driver not found ! Root hub present, usb host
>   mode is active
>
> under usb: 2-1 0179:0bda Realtek 802.11n NIC
>
> 1-1 0001:0a12 Bluetooth v 2.0 Bluetooth v 2.0 dongle

As per your doubt, BT dongle is not recognised by "Android". This BT dongle, when plugged to Windows XP computer, it is recognised by computer.

Comment: please post this question to usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go

Comment: You say "it" recognizes the dongle, what is "it"? Android or the app? Which app?

Answer (score 1):

According to some sources, Bluetooth dongle support was added in Android 4.2.2, and it requires some effort from the ROM developers, so it's not in every Android version. You should either ask the manufacturer for a ROM that supports BT dongles, or try to find a custom ROM like CyanogenMod for your device that has the support.

Sources: [Does Android 4.2.2 support usb bluetooth dongle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608727/does-android-4-2-2-support-usb-bluetooth-dongle)

[Bluetooth dongle via OTG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2235485)